# Trying to verify date on sheet1 in one cell with 30 columns on sheet 2 once verified with vba data pastes under date in sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, button, excel-formula

I work for a local company that uses antiquated systems relying on much manual data entry.  Trying to ease the pain with some faster capabilities using excel vba and formulas.  I've built a spreadsheet filled with formulas and vba buttons.  I'm literally on the last part and have been stuck now for at least 2 weeks.  Time is now running out and I'm hoping for some assistance.

Spreadsheet has 2 sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". On Sheet1 I use a button to concatenate and move data into one cell which is L11.  In L8 I have a constant changing date, day by day.  The data entry works like this: I enter data for April 11th and then change the date in L8 to April 14th (could be any day, just using 14 as an example) to enter the next set of data.  On Sheet2 I have each column labeled by days in the month, i.e. Column A = 1-Apr, Column B = 2-Apr, Column C = 3-Apr, etc.... to the end of the month 30 or 31 which equals Column AD or AE.

What I'd like for the code to do is move the data from cell L11 on sheet1, based on the date in L8 on sheet1, the data moves from sheet1 to sheet2 under the corresponding date. So the click of a button, the macro/vba code finds the date on sheet2 and looks for the date in L8 sheet1 and says:
    "I see a date of 17-Apr in L8, what data exists in cell L11 on sheet1? Ahhh ok.. there is data in L11 sheet1.  I will go ahead and take that data from L11 and paste it in column 17(column Q) in the next available slot below.  Then I will make sure the data is removed from Sheet1 and put the user back on Sheet1 ready to be used again."

Please keep in mind that the data that exists in L8 sheet1 (the date) contains a vlookup formula.  If that is not needed, I'll gladly take other ideas on matching dates.  Or for that matter any other ideas that are better than what you see above and below I'm always open to suggestions.  Also, the button I use to concatenate data that ultimately ends up in cell L11 sheet1 is a recorded macro.  Basically I recorded copying specific cells and pasting them together in one cell and then inserted a single cell that pushes the concatenated data down one cell so that I could enter more than one set of data.

This is the most recent code I've been working on.  When I used the loops for i and j, the code did not error out, however it didn't do anything when running.  I recently tried adding k and m, but the wall I'm hitting just won't budge.  Help please...

```
Sub senddatatosheet2()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim mydate As String
    lastrow1 = Sheets("sheet1").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To 8
        For k = 11 To 11
            mydate = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value

            Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For j = 1 To lastrow2
                For m = 2 To lastrow2
                    If Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(j, "A")).Value = mydate Then
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(11, "L")).Copy
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "AD")).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                    End If
                Next j
            Next m

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next i
    Next k

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you could sub your question down and attach a screenshot? It's a lot to read and we all have the attention spans of a gnat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong...

1. You enter the date in Sheet1!L8, then enter whatever data you want into whatever cells you do, which is all concatenated into Sheet1!L11.
2. You want to transfer the data in Sheet1!L11 into say Sheet1!xy (where x=the column for the data to go into for that day and y=the next empty row), who's date is in Sheet1!x1 and it matches the date in Sheet1!L8

If so, the following should do:

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

```
Sub btnNext_Click()

Dim MyDate As Date
Dim ColFound As Long, NextRowToUse As Long, MyData As String
Dim RowThatContainsDates As Long


'Enter the row that contains the dates across the top
RowThatContainsDates = 1


'Get the date from Sheet1!L8
MyDate = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(8, 12).Value

'Get the data from Sheet1!L11
MyData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 12).Value


'Get the column where the date in Sheet1!L8 is found
ColFound = Worksheets("sheet2").Rows(RowThatContainsDates).Find(MyDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

'Get the next row to use for the selected Column
NextRowToUse = 1
Do While Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(NextRowToUse, ColFound).Value <> ""
    NextRowToUse = NextRowToUse + 1
Loop

'Duplicate the text from Sheet1!l1 to the Row and Column found
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRowToUse, ColFound).Value = MyData

'Clear the contents of the cells containing the original data
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L3:L6").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost exactly to the point Aubs! Seriously super excited here! There is only one little thing that is either not working right or the code isn't there... I put the code you provided in and it works perfectly.  The one thing that doesn't seem to happen is on Sheet2 after I activate the button, the data in row 3 is overwritten.  Is there a way for the code to look for the next available cell below.  Example: Column C has data entered in row 3, the date doesn't change in L8, new data is generated in L11, button activate and data entered on sheet2 row 4 under existing data and so on???

Comment: Nevermind my friend! You made that code.  Talk about perfecto! Thank you ever so kindly.  I'll provide an up vote on this code and hope that others find this useful too.  Again, I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: I did notice however one thing.  The code you wrote above on the line that states "Duplicate the text from Sheet1!L11 to the Row and Column found" does something strange.  If I leave it be as is the way you wrote it, upon activation of the code the data goes in row 3.  If I activate the button again the data from sheet1!L11 goes over to Sheet2 with the corresponding date, however it overwrites the data that is already there under the date instead of adding to the column.  I tried changing the range in ColFound to ("A1:AE1") and deleted row one.  That worked once.... then....

Comment: i went to delete the data that was added to the fields under the dates in Sheet2 and the next attempt at activating the code errors out.  I managed to figure out that it happens only after I hit the delete key.  I tried creating another macro to see if clearcontents would work.  Unfortunately it too acted as a delete key function resulting in the error when I try to activate the code.  Figured out then that if I reinsert row 1, move the dates down to row 2, and change Colfound back to ("A2:AE2"), and then rerun code it works.  Any suggestions???

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I think I know why. If you look at the second screenshot, row1 has the day, row2 has the date. I should have clarified in my post that you need to have two rows of data first, otherwise the `Worksheets("sheet2").Columns(ColFound).End(xlDown).Row` finds takes you to the bottom of the sheet (i.e. the very last row). Did you just have one row, or two?

Comment: Indeed I did.  Started thinking that this may have been the case five minutes before logging on this morning.  I put the first row back in and changed the code to precisely the way you had it and it works.  :)If you're interested in furthering this conversation perhaps we could do the code without row 1 or column A being a requirement.  For now, you have sincerely helped a fellow out big time! :)... Thank you so kindly friend...

Comment: I've updated my answer (you might need to re-mark it as an answer?).  There's a new variable to set the row that contains your dates.  I've removed column A and also set it so you can have an (almost) infinite number of columns in use - Rather than specifying RANGE, I've changed it to ROWS to look in to find the correct date.  Similarly, it'll also go on (almost) infinitely for however many rows until it finds a blank one.